# TYPO3 - Contents are displayed twice on translate

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I'm using TYPO3 9.5 and I'm trying to translate page using the Copy process from TYPO3,
The Problem that the content are displayed twice when I change to other language beside the default language (EN).

```
 languages:
 -
  title: English
  enabled: true
  languageId: '0'
  base: /
  typo3Language: default
  locale: en_US.UTF-8
  iso-639-1: en
  navigationTitle: EN
  hreflang: en-US
  direction: ''
  flag: en-us-gb
 -
 title: Deutsch
 enabled: true
 languageId: '1'
 base: /de/
 typo3Language: de
 locale: de_DE.UTF-8
 iso-639-1: de
 navigationTitle: de
 hreflang: de-DE
 direction: ''
 fallbackType: fallback
 fallbacks: '0'
 flag: de
```

In my config I have tried to use: `languageField = sys_language_uid`

```
  select {
        orderBy = sorting
        languageField = sys_language_uid###
        where = {#colPos}={register:colPos}
        where.insertData = 1
        pidInList.data = register:pageUid
        pidInList.override.data = register:contentFromPid
    }
```

But will always display the default language(EN) but if use :

```
        includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
```

The content will displayed twice in the Default language and the selected language .

Edit :

```
  config {
      absRefPrefix = auto
      no_cache = {$config.no_cache}
      uniqueLinkVars = 1
      noPageTitle = 2
      linkVars = L
      prefixLocalAnchors = {$config.prefixLocalAnchors}
      renderCharset = utf-8
      metaCharset = utf-8
      doctype = html5
      removeDefaultJS = {$config.removeDefaultJS}
      inlineStyle2TempFile = 0
      admPanel = {$config.admPanel}
      debug = 0
      cache_period = 86400
      sendCacheHeaders = {$config.sendCacheHeaders}
      enableContentLengthHeader = 1
      intTarget = 0
      disablePrefixComment = 1
      index_enable = 1
      index_externals = 1
      index_metatags = 1
      headerComment = 0
      contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
      compressJs = 0
      compressCss = 0
      concatenateJs = 0
      concatenateCss = 0
    }
```

The Problem was solved for the double content in the config yml :

```
fallbackType: strict
```

Comment: Change the fallback type to free mode.

Comment: I did it but nothing change

Comment: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/ContentMapping/Index.html I am using Extension it's the same

Answer (score 0):

The options languageField and pidInList will be detected automatically to match the current page and language while respecting the table you are trieng to fetch. For testing purposes you may only use "< styles.content.get" to fetch the content of colPos=0 of the current page.

However I think your problem is located somewhere else in your configuration. Do you also setup some language settings of the config.-Typoscript-Section like sys_language_uid depending on the "L"-GET-Var?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so I am not using "L"-GET-Var, the only setting for the language I have posted but in my config I don't have any section depending on language or L"-GET-Var or sys_language_uid

Comment: Should I post my config file ?

Comment: Thats maybe helpful.

Comment: I Post it in my question .

Comment: How is your PAGE build up with? How do you transfer / output the content to the Frontend (how does the output work) ?

Comment: I have build my own content in other extension (cType)

Comment: Sorry, but I was had updated my question : my problem that I see the default language content and the selected language, for example if I have a content element (cType) in default language and I translated to German and when I choose (DE) from the menu, the element will display in English and German

Comment: fallbackType: strict
was causing the problem